Formatting a cite insite a text block
straightforward question.
How do I manage text cite inside sections? Like in the picture I want to constrict the text section. There must be an easy way to do that.


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Aside: What you call a "cite" is more commonly called a quote or quotation.

You wrote,

There must be an easy way to do that.

Indeed. It's called a quote environment.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{lipsum}     % filler text

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{3}

\subsection{Relevanz und Verortung}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begin{quote}
-- \emph{Aussage Interview 1} Zitat: \lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{quote}

\subsection{Zielgruppe}

\lipsum[3][1-6]

\end{document}

